# elusive c function declared in header

Tags: c

Here is the C file:
http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/rng/WELL19937a.c (I uncommented, as L'Ecuyer told to)

Here is the C header:
http://simul.iro.umontreal.ca/rng/WELL19937a.h

The question is: where is this **double (*WELLRNG19937a) (void)** in C file?

I don't see it. But it exists. This code works on TIGCC but yields 0.

```
#include "WELL44497a.h"
#include <tigcclib.h>
void _main(void)
 {
 unsigned int u=33337;
InitWELLRNG44497a(&u); //this function probably wants array of good seeds but I don't have them.

double a = WELLRNG44497a()  ;
clrscr();
printf("%f",a);
ngetchx();//wait for keyboard input
}
```

Deleting InitWELLRNG44497a(&u) makes it throw SIGSEGV (which assures me the other function exists)

I will be very greatful if you tell me where is this function. Even more, if you tell me how to use this function.

PS. have nothing to clarify anymore. This was very stupid question, but has been answered right. Reason for function giving zeroes all the time was different.

Comment: I don't understand.  It's right there, in the C file you linked to.

Comment: It's a function pointer, which is initialized in the init function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`double (*WELLRNG19937a) (void)`  is a pointer to a `double funcname (void)` function.

In the first function

```
void InitWELLRNG19937a (unsigned int *init)
```

you can see

`WELLRNG19937a = case_1;`

**where case_1 is**

`double case_1 (void)`

Then in main you are calling a function poited by `WELLRNG19937a` pointer. The real called function will be `case_1`.

**Deleting InitWELLRNG44497a(&u) makes it throw SIGSEGV**

This causes segfault because of is `InitWELLRNG44497a` that init the function pointer, otherwise the pointer is uninitialized.

Comment: ...and `InitWELLRNG44497a()` probably sets the pointer up to the actual function.  hence, when `InitWELLRNG44497a` isn't called you get the seg fault.

Comment: thank you. Probably silly question, but was puzzling to me. These zeroes were thrown because of default int size on ti89 calculator and because of bad seed. Changing seed to 1391 and ints to long ints makes it work.

Comment: Not so stupid. I asked to admin to reopen it, but....

Comment: The question was silly but clear at least. I got exact answer... So in C you can change a function inside another function (if it is declared). Great.